# Changing NA values to mean function returning Null dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a= c(5,6,2,NA,8,NA,1,5,NA,9,NA,0,2,5,NA,8),b= c(5,2,2,1,NA,NA,11,5,1,NA,9,NA,9,2,NA,NA), d= c(2,6,NA,NA,11,NA,1,2,NA,9,4,0,2,5,6,NA))

missing <- function(data){
  for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
    data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

> df <- missing(df)
> df
NULL
```

Not sure what I have done wrong

```
data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
```

This statement alone works like intended, but when I put it inside a function, all it does it make my dataframe null

Comment: Add `return (data)` or just `data` at the end of the function.

Comment: `library(zoo); na.aggregate(DF)`

Comment: @Fernando Thank you that solved the problem. I have to create my own function and input the mean if it is a continuous value or input the mode if it is categorical. That is why I am going this funky method